# Even number of td elements in table with odd number of columns

Tags: html, css, html-table, center, offset

I feel like this is one of those well covered questions, but I was having a hard time finding a straight answer or solution.

According to the W3 spec on tables:

> The number of columns is equal to the number of columns required by the row with the most columns, including cells that span multiple columns. For any row that has fewer than this number of columns, the end of that row should be padded with empty cells.

This is certainly apparent and makes sense, but I don't think it's unreasonable to want to center a particular row's contents if it does not reach the row width.

In my case I have a table of icons 3 columns wide, but there are 11 icons leaving the last row off center. I've been struggling to come up with a way around this, but all I can think of is to do something hacky or make a new table with two columns just for those icons.

Some sample code to illustrate the problem:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>       
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I want

```
000 000 000
  000 000
```

What I get

```
000 000 000
000 000
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please share some code?

Comment: Eh sure, but this question really doesn't require any.

Comment: A code would explain things better than imagining things.

Comment: I just read your last paragraph about "In my case" and this is why I asked for it :)

Comment: Updated. Gets across what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without css nested tables

```html
<table border="1">
     <tr>
        <td> 
          <table border="1">
            <tr>
             <td>Content</td>
             <td>Content</td>
             <td>Content</td>       
           </tr>    
         </table>
      </td>              
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" border="1">
               <tr>
                 <td align="center">Content</td>
                 <td align="center">Content</td>              
              </tr>   
            </table>
        </td>       
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This did the trick for me but boy is it ugly. My particular case was not as simple as the sample code I posted however, so for anyone that has the same problem, try the others first. This is definitely a last resort.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a little trick to fix this issue. Use the following css.
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/246p82gs/1/)

```
table {
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
}
table tbody {
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
}
table tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
table tr td {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This works in Chrome, but not in Firefox (not sure of Safari/IE).

Comment: How is that doing that? Can you explain?

Comment: @GHOST-34- Are you sure it is not working on firefox? Because it is working at my end. What version you are using ?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Nothing complex in doing that. We are just changing the display type of table.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use CSS, this native trick might help you.
CSS Flexbox might not work on all browsers.

> **Formula** 
>   TotalColSpan = LowerBox * UpperBox;
>   Upper row colspan = TotalColSpan / LowerBox;
>   Lower row colspan = TotalColSpan / UpperBox;

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Content</td>
        <td colspan="2">Content</td>
        <td colspan="2">Content</td>       
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Content</td>
        <td colspan="3">Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT 1:**

How this one is working? [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8Ls4w9on/)

We have used tables colspan attributes, The colspan attribute defines the number of columns a cell should span.

[image]

When we write `colspan="2"`, that means there is actually two cells, but they are merged. Here we written 3 `colspan="2"`, that means we have actually 6 table cells. In next row, we can split this 6 Table cells. We haved used `colspan="3"` in 2nd row, that means it will take 3 cells and merge.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>     
        <td>Content</td>     
        <td>Content</td>     
        <td>Content</td>     
        <td>Content</td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Content</td>
        <td colspan="2">Content</td>
        <td colspan="2">Content</td>           
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Content</td>
        <td colspan="3">Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```